# How to create a modular environment that doesn't repeat itself?

Tags: textures, unreal-4, materials

I am creating a modular environment for a game so I have walls repeating quite often. What I want to achieve is to have the same walls with a different look, even though they are the same mesh sharing the same UV map. I took a screenshot of what I would like to achieve, the same walls repeating but with different stains across them. I should specify that I dont' want to use unique materials but only tileable materials for optimization reasons.

[image]

---

I thought of using decals but i don't like them too much, is there an alternative?

Comment: I've seen this done with tiling "detail maps" or "grunge maps" that layer with the base texture, but have a different (usually much lower) tiling frequency - so the same patch of grime won't overlap the same  part of the underlying texture when it repeats, making the blended result look more unique. Have you investigated something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use them but I don't really like this workflow and the result I got. Maybe it's my fault though definitely gonna check them more in-depth if I don't find a better alternative, thanks!

Comment: Want to show us how you used that workflow, what result you got, and what you're unsatisfied with about it? This can help focus answers on improvements that address those particular issues.